# "Times ahead of us" vs. "times ahead for us"

Tags: expressions

What is the difference between these two phrases?

> good times ahead **of** us
>
> good times ahead **for** us

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're just differently created constructions, but in the end, they both mean the same. Consider the following:

> There are good times ahead.

This is a perfectly grammatical, self-sufficient sentence. You can expand it by stating either:

A) Ahead of what those times are?

B) For whom those times are?

The result?

> A) There are good times ahead of us.
>
> B) There are good times ahead for us.

Since *ahead of us* is more commonly used, especially in other fields, it's more natural for use. You could hear it a lot during plane flights, for example:

> Ladies and gentleman, there is a storm ahead of us.

Comment: I agree that in the end they both mean much the same, but as literal interpretation would suggest, *ahead for us* implies more of a sense that those good times are *specifically arranged for us*. Whereas something *ahead of us* might just happen to be wherever it is. Since in this case it's *in the future*, we'll simply be carried towards it by the Arrow of Time.

Answer (score 1):

While I think both are grammatically equivalent phrases, I have never seen "ahead for us" in common use.  You would say "ahead of us".

This is supported by Google ngram showing the relative usage of the two terms.

[image]

When the "for" version is used, it seems to be emphasizing that there's an emotional distance between the speaker and the people who have something ahead of them.

> There are exciting times ahead for international businesses.

versus

> There are exciting times ahead of us.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a difference in meaning, or at least in emphasis. *There are good times ahead of us* doesn't specify who the times are good for. *There are good times ahead for us* does.